# how to save image over IP address instead of local directory in spring

Tags: java, spring

Currently, image is uploading on this path:

```
D:\\Java Workspace\\arana-master\\arana-master\\build\\web\\/resources/docUploads\\1519817341555.jpg"
```

My code:

```
 String ax[] = ext.split("\\.");
 String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
 String filePath = rootDirectory+"/resources/docUploads"+File.separator+System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+ax[ax.length-1];
 file.transferTo(new File(filePath));
```

I want to get current IP address and Port where a web is running and save it in this format:

**http://192.168.225.34:8084/resources/docUploads/156565645345434.jpg**

If current session is closed means if a user is logout then the image will not be shown to a user. By copy the path to the browser.

if I use iP address I got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\Users\\PRIYA JAIN\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.2\\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\ROOT\\tmp\\http:\\192.168.225.34:8084\\resources\\docUploads\\1519822047950.jpg
```

Comment: you can add this image to your project and can read it from there..

Comment: I am uploading an image from Android project and java project as well. If I am getting absolute path how can I view it on app side?

Comment: view edit, please.